# How to fix skipping a process in a loop in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, performance-testing

Basically I want to get a string variable, then check my one of my firebase database's node to see if a child of that string exist, if it does, I want values specific to that string to be added to my database, but the execution isn't happening one after the other, the loop doesn't wait always for the whole checking if the string exist as a child in the database, it skips it sometimes and hence values that are supposed to be added aren't all being added

I'm running this operation on a separate thread, by the way

```
      count = i;
        Elements mShowUpdateName = doc.select("div[class=data main]").select("b").eq(i);
        mUpdateName = mShowUpdateName.text();


        Elements mShowEpisodeDate = doc.select("div[class=data main]").eq(i);
        mEpisodeDate = mShowEpisodeDate.text();


        int startIndex = mUpdateName.indexOf("-");

        mSeriesName = mEpisodeDate.substring(0,startIndex-1);
        Log.e("child" , mSeriesName);


        usersTVSeriesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String mString = mSeriesName.replace(".", "");
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(mString)){

                    int first = mEpisodeDate.indexOf("-");
                    int second = mEpisodeDate.indexOf("-", first + 1);

                    String season = mEpisodeDate.substring(first+1, second);


                    second = mEpisodeDate.indexOf("-", first + 1);
                    int last = mEpisodeDate.lastIndexOf("-");

                    String episode = mEpisodeDate.substring(second+1, last);

                    int startIndexDate = mEpisodeDate.indexOf("[");
                    int endIndexDate = mEpisodeDate.lastIndexOf("]");
                    String date = mEpisodeDate.substring(startIndexDate +1 , endIndexDate);


                    HashMap<String, Object> showsMap = new HashMap<>();

                    showsMap.put("date" , date);
                    showsMap.put("episode" , episode);
                    showsMap.put("season", season);
                    showsMap.put("string", mEpisodeDate);

                    showsMap.put("index", Integer.toString(count));
                    showsMap.put("name", mSeriesName);


                    updateRef.child(mString).child(episode).updateChildren(showsMap);

                    }
                else {
                    Log.e("no", "no new updates");
                    Log.e("no", mSeriesName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
```

I want it to always check if the value exists in the database, and then do accordingly

Currently the log is

```
E/loop: Step 1. String: Will And Grace
E/loop: Step 1. String: The Grand Tour
E/loop: Step 1. String: The Good Fight
E/loop: Step 1. String: Hanna
E/loop: Step 1. String: What We Do in the Shadows
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
    Step 3. value doesn't exist
    Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. value doesn't exist
    Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
    Step 3. value doesn't exist
E/loop: Step 1. String: Jane The Virgin
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. adding value to database
E/loop: Step 1. String: Chicago PD
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. adding value to database
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. adding value to database
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. adding value to database
```

What I want is for it to always follow step 1, 2, 3 e.g

```
E/loop: Step 1. String: Chicago Med
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. adding value to database
E/loop: Step 1. String: Chicago Fire
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. adding value to database
E/loop: Step 1. String: MotherFatherSon
E/loop: Step 2. checking if the value exists in the database
E/loop: Step 3. value doesn't exist
```

Comment: What do you mean through "the loop doesn't wait always for the whole checking "?

Comment: The loop is to do 3 things:  1. Get a string variable, 2. Check if its exists in the database 3. Add A value to the database, I guess checking it the value exists takes up some time so the loop doesn't always do that, rather it goes to next iteration